# Почему закрыли этот вопрос?, или Вопрос который якобы не по теме

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

Я тут наткнулся на вот [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1213803/pygame-%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-pygame-keydown/) вопрос. Он не мой, а другого челика. Его прикрыли через день, потому что этот вопрос "не по теме". Но если вы посмотрите этот вопрос, то он вроде бы по теме программирования... или нет?

В общем, кто нибудь может объяснить мне почему этот вопрос закрыли? Мне кажется что если этот вопрос и достоин закрытия, то по другой причине, а не потому что он не по теме.

Comment: Посмелюсь предположить, что большинство голосов за закрытие было поставлено до того, как ТС выложил код.

Comment: ммм, понятно, а переоткрыть можно, раз он уже код добавил? или надо было раньше?

Comment: код был еще вчера

Comment: Последный голос за закрытие был сделан спустя 5 часов после появления кода в вопросе. Так что остальные могли быть сделаны до этого. Переоткрыть можно, но для этого также нужно пять голосов или щепотка модераторской пыльцы.

Comment: Да... там просто не было кoда, когда я его закрывал — теперь переоткроем ;)

Comment: Код есть, нажал "переоткрыть" (хотя если там правда дело в какой-то незакрытой скобке, вопрос могут опять закрыть за опечатку)

Comment: @alex9127, кажется [переоткрыли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1213803/232)

Comment: @andreymal круто

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот таймлайн - 4 голоса из 5 были даны до добавления кода в вопрос:

```
2020-12-05 00:30:53Z   закрыть   голос     0xdb
2020-12-04 19:22:47Z   история   изменён   xmurik
2020-12-04 13:12:19Z   закрыть   голос     Victor VosMottor
2020-12-04 09:56:53Z   закрыть   голос     S. Nick
2020-12-04 07:21:33Z   закрыть   голос     aleksandr barakin
2020-12-04 05:14:03Z   закрыть   голос     Danis
```

Для закрытия потому и требуется 5 голосов, что один или два человека могут ошибиться. В данном случае так сложилось, что 4 голоса были даны до правки вопроса вполне справедливо, а вот пятый по сути единолично закрыл изменённый вопрос. Такое иногда случается, стоит просто брать и переоткрывать.

Comment: А что ж 0xdb то закрыл ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, не знаю, но это и по обычной истории редактирования видно, что он закрыл сильно позже правки.

Comment: ну походу ему что то было неясно этому 0xdb

Comment: Добавил голос за закрытие, т.к. приведенное описание и код не MCVE. Судя по ответам, там или опечатка, или достаточно фрагмента обработки нажатия кнопок.